# Why can't I pass dependencies task when I bundle tasks in Gulp

Tags: build, gulp

If I execute this code it will throw an error saying it only accepts a function instead of the three tasks

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], ['styles', 'scripts', 'images']);
```

I want to execute the clean task before the other three,
I don't want to wire the clean task to each single task when I define them as clean will delete my whole build folder.

How do I do it?

This is the API reference https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn

Comment: what if i put it like this `gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'styles', 'scripts', 'images']);` will the tasks be synchronous or not?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, use the run-sequence plugin to run tasks in order https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
    runSequence('clean',
                ['styles', 'scripts', 'images']);
});
```

This until Gulp 4.0 which will support gulp.series and gulp.parallel natively and it will look something like this

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('styles', 'scripts', 'images')));
```

Answer (score 0):

With

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'styles', 'scripts', 'images']);

The clean task would be the first task that build is dependent upon to be launched however they will all be launched in parallel.   That clean is launched first is due to the implemention and may change without notice.

This should work:

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function(cb)
{
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
  runSequence( ['styles', 'scripts', 'images']);
} );
```